# How to handle a stream of files in rust?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, rust-cargo

My goal is to have my cli program accept a stream of files

eg. Directory `example_data` has the following files

- `a.txt`
- `b.txt`
- `c.txt`

I would like my rust program to handle something like the following

`cargo run < example_data/*.txt`

Is this type of setup possible? What's an alternative to this? I don't want to have to pass the file names individually to the program. Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't really a Rust question since the behavior is dictated by the shell. `cargo run <a.txt` will redirect the file contents into the program's stdin, but only one file, it doesn't work for globs (i.e. `*`s for multiple files). You can do `cargo run *.txt` which will send multiple *arguments* to the process. You can access those in Rust via [`std::env::args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.args.html).

Comment: See `std::io::stdin()`

Comment: Note that if you just want all the files con**cat**enated together, that's what `cat` is for. That is, `whatever < example_data/*.txt` does not work, because the wildcard is not expanded in that position, but in `cat example_data/*.txt | whatever` the wildcard gets expanded and `cat` combines the files in one stream that is passes to the standard input of whatever. Whatever might be `cargo run`, that is rather incidental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can call your program with `*.txt`, the shell will pass multiple arguments to your program (depends on the shell). You can access program arguments in Rust via [`std::env::args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.args.html):

```
> cargo run *.txt
```

```
fn main() {
    for arg in std::env::args().skip(1) {
        println!("arg: {}", arg);
    }
}
```

```
arg: a.txt
arg: b.txt
arg: c.txt
```

You can then process the file names as you wish.